# mysql giving deprecated warning

Tags: mysql

I have been receiving a warning(its flooded my logs) since updating mysql.It states,

```
 1287, "'@@tx_isolation' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '@@transaction_isolation' instead"
```

under mysql

```
mysql> show variables like "tx_isolation";
+---------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name | Value           |
+---------------+-----------------+
| tx_isolation  | REPEATABLE-READ |
+---------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I also have the new variable that the warning suggests..

```
mysql> show variables like "transaction_isolation";
+-----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name         | Value           |
+-----------------------+-----------------+
| transaction_isolation | REPEATABLE-READ |
+-----------------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec
```

Im aware that the variablew is no longer in use.  I want it gone but am cautious with my queries. Is the proper procedure to delete the warning variable.  If so, how?

Also checking my.cnf, i do not see any mention of either variables.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[The problem](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4120) is [resolved in SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/pull/391), [released as a part of version 1.2.0](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/changelog/changelog_12.html?highlight=tx_isolation#change-947df4a451b5fdefb3815b93f55b4d8f), [backported to 1.1.15](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/changelog/changelog_11.html?highlight=tx_isolation#change-364804fd47128c29140cfd2c6f8b8063) and it was rolled out 2017-11-03. By upgrading SQLAlchemy to 1.1.15 the warning disappears.

```
pip install sqlalchemy>=1.1.15
```

Answer (score 2):

From MySQL 5.7.20 onwards you should changeover to using transaction_isolation. In documentation it states:

> Prior to MySQL 5.7.20, use tx_isolation rather than
>   transaction_isolation.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html

**tx_isolation**

```
Deprecated  5.7.20
System Variable Name    tx_isolation
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tx_isolation

**transaction_isolation**

```
Command-Line Format         --transaction-isolation=name
System Variable (>= 5.7.20) Name    transaction_isolation
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_transaction_isolation

EDIT:

Instead of relying on the old variable, start using the new variable, as in the examples provided by the documentation

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.transaction_isolation, @@transaction_isolation; 
SET GLOBAL transaction_isolation='REPEATABLE-READ'; 
SET SESSION transaction_isolation='SERIALIZABLE';
```

You will have to search through your code to identify where the deprecated variable has been used, and substitute it with the new variable/syntax.

Comment: i read that as well, but the documents does not state how to remove the tx_isolation variable to stop the warning.  It is ruining my error logs with million lines of warnings.

Comment: You don't have to remove it. You just have to stop using it.

Comment: @Anekdotin do you understand that the warning is being triggered because either your code, or a library you are using, is actively setting or getting the value of `@@tx_isolation`?  It's not the fact that the variable is on the server.  It's that your code somehow is accessing it using the deprecated name.

Comment: Im using pymysql, and i commented on his git as an issue.  He exclaims its my usage.  I have never heard of this variable before this issue.  Im not sure where to go at this point. Also using the commands above did not help with the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I got the error while using pymysql library in a flask setup. Downgrading to mysql 5.6 works but maybe not the best solution.

Comment: I also filed a support case on the github page so lets hope he fix the issue. Otherwise it seems to be to only change on row of code so maybe I fix the pymysql myself until he fix the issue.

Comment: I commented and he didnt seem to happy about it and deleted my git issue.  It looks easy to fix under cursors.py

Comment: The problem will be resolved in SQLAlchemy as a part of version 1.1.15 and according to the developers that release will hopefully be rolled out later this week and then the problem will be gone :) So upgrade SQLAlchemy to 1.1.15 will also be a solution in a couple of days :)

Answer (score 0):

I installed sqlalchemy==1.1.15 and the problem was the same. So, I change the command in base.py of sqlalchemy as follows:

```
    #cursor.execute('SELECT @@tx_isolation')
    cursor.execute('SELECT @@transaction_isolation')
```

You must start a fresh python in order to see the change.